# Volley Android: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Sorry again,
trying to perform a POST call to an URL.

I'm following this tutorial (http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/) for the part of ApplicationController.

My VolleyController is the same of his ApplicationController, this is my LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final static String API_URL_LOGIN = "http://www.xxxx/account";
    private static String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;

    private String jsonResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

    }

public void performLogin(View view) {

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        final String username_text = username.getText().toString();
        final String password_text = password.getText().toString();

        Log.d(TAG, username_text);


        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username", username_text);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(API_URL_LOGIN, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        // add the request object to the queue to be executed
        VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

    }
```

And this is my activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_username" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:onClick="performLogin" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The error is

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.webtemplum.hq60.LoginActivity.performLogin(LoginActivity.java:121)
```

And line 121 is `VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);`

This is VolleyController

```
package com.webtemplum.hq60;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class VolleyController extends Application {

    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";

    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    /**
     * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
     */
    private static VolleyController sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize the singleton
        sInstance = this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
     */
    public static synchronized VolleyController getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
     */
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
        // created when it is accessed for the first time
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
     * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

        VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param tag
     */
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TAG);

        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    /**
     * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
     * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
     *
     * @param tag
     */
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webtemplum.hq60" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your `VolleyController`

Comment: Dont you have to send password as param along with username

Comment: @Clairvoyant I know, but in that case I would not have a null pointer exception but an error answer from webserver...

Comment: post your AndroidManifest

Comment: @Blackbelt just done

Comment: remove `username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);` these two line from performLogin() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your application tag add

```
  <application 
       android:name=".VolleyController"
       // the rest stays the same
```

you are getting NPE because you are not using your subclass of `Application`